# Filter array with JSONS with more than one conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I have the following array

```
 let tableA=[{id:'1', name:'name1',age:'31',gender:'male',class='B'},
             {id:'2', name:'name2',age:'38',gender:'male',class='A'},
             {id:'3', name:'name3',age:'35',gender:'male',class='C'},
             {id:'4', name:'name4',age:'20',gender:'female',class='B'},
             {id:'5', name:'name5',age:'19',gender:'female',class='A'},
             {id:'6', name:'name6',age:'31',gender:'male',class='A'}
            ];
```

and this array for filters

```
 let filters = [{type:'gender',value:"male"}, {type:'age',value:"31"}];
```

I'm trying to filter tableA with the values of table filters, all filters must match. Filters are not static, it means that filters can include json files for all table keys.

So far I'm trying to filter table_A with the code above.

```
 let filtered_table=[];
 tableA.forEach(row => {
    filters.map((item) => {
        if(row[item.type]==item.value){
           filtered_table.push(row);
         }
     });
});
console.log(filtered_table);
```

the result of the code above is:

```
 [ { id: '1', name: 'name1', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'B' },
   { id: '1', name: 'name1', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'B' },
   { id: '2', name: 'name2', age: '38', gender: 'male', class: 'A' },
   { id: '3', name: 'name3', age: '35', gender: 'male', class: 'C' },
   { id: '6', name: 'name6', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'A' },
   { id: '6', name: 'name6', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'A' } ]
```

How I can get back only the row that match for all of the filters_table items combined? For this example I'm expecting this:

```
[ { id: '1', name: 'name1', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'B' },
  { id: '6', name: 'name6', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'A' } ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let filtered_table=[];
 tableA.forEach(row => {
    const flag = filters.map((item) => {
        if(row[item.type]==item.value){
           return 1;
         } else {
           return 0;
         }
     });
     if(flag.filter(el=>el != 1).length==0) {
        filtered_table.push(row);   
     }
});
console.log(filtered_table);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple with js `.filter()`. [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
Its looping every element in `tableA` and filter out the gender and the age

```js
 let tableA = [{
     id: '1',
     name: 'name1',
     age: '31',
     gender: 'male',
     class: 'B'
   },
   {
     id: '2',
     name: 'name2',
     age: '38',
     gender: 'male',
     class: 'A'
   },
   {
     id: '3',
     name: 'name3',
     age: '35',
     gender: 'male',
     class: 'C'
   },
   {
     id: '4',
     name: 'name4',
     age: '20',
     gender: 'female',
     class: 'B'
   },
   {
     id: '5',
     name: 'name5',
     age: '19',
     gender: 'female',
     class: 'A'
   },
   {
     id: '6',
     name: 'name6',
     age: '31',
     gender: 'male',
     class: 'A'
   }
 ];
 
 let fil = [{
   type: 'gender',
   value: "male"
 }, {
   type: 'age',
   value: "31"
 }];


const data = tableA.filter((ele,index) => {
    return ele.gender == fil[0].value && ele.age == fil[1].value
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're after is the `.every` method [See Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
var filters = [
  { type: "gender", value: "male" },
  { type: "age", value: "31" },
];


var tableA = [
  { id: "1", name: "name1", age: "31", gender: "male", class: "B" },
  { id: "2", name: "name2", age: "38", gender: "male", class: "A" },
  { id: "3", name: "name3", age: "35", gender: "male", class: "C" },
  { id: "4", name: "name4", age: "20", gender: "female", class: "B" },
  { id: "5", name: "name5", age: "19", gender: "female", class: "A" },
  { id: "6", name: "name6", age: "31", gender: "male", class: "A" },
]

var result = tableA.filter(item =>
  filters.every(filter => item[filter.type] === filter.value)
);

console.log(result)

//  [ { id: '1', name: 'name1', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'B' },
//    { id: '6', name: 'name6', age: '31', gender: 'male', class: 'A' } ]
```

Below is a more verbose way, not using the ES6 Syntax:

```
var result tableA.filter(item => {
  //ensure every filter has been matched against
  var everyFilterMatched = filters.every(filter => {
    return item[filter.type] === filter.value;
  });
  return everyFilterMatched
});
```

N.B: Edit is use `every` as I am assuming you may not know how many filters you will have, just that there is an array of the given shape, and you want to match **all* of them.